# How do i format the response from watson conversation to show user?

Tags: python-2.7, watson-conversation

i am working in pycharm and just doing a simple interaction with the watson conversation service where you ask it a questione and it responds, however the response from watson sends all sorts of other info as well that i don't want to display, i only want to display the answer and then let the user enter another question. The code is below can anyone help with this?

```
import json
import watson_developer_cloud

conversation = watson_developer_cloud.ConversationV1(username='', password='', version='2018-03-16')
question = raw_input("what is youre question?\n")
response = conversation.message( workspace_id='*', input={ 'text': question }) 
print(json.dumps(response, indent=2))
```

Watson then responds with:

```
{ "entities": [], "intents": [ { "confidence": 1, "intent": "hello" } ], "output": { "text": [ "Good day to you.." ], "log_messages": [], "nodes_visited": [ "node_12_1519477177015" ] }, "context": { "conversation_id": "", "system": { "dialog_stack": [ { "dialog_node": "root" } ], "dialog_request_counter": 1, "dialog_turn_counter": 1, "branch_exited": true, "_node_output_map": { "node_12_1519477177015": [ 0 ] }, "branch_exited_reason": "completed" } }, "input": { "text": "hello" } }   
Process finished with exit code 0
```

I can see the response is in there but it doesn't seem to be in a variable i can call with the print command.

Answer (score 0):

The result is in `response`, which is an object.

You can access the text from Watson with:

```
print('\n'.join(response['output']['text']))
```

Comment: how do i get it to loop back to the user to enter another line of dialogue after the response?